# Doesn't Calling Copy Constructor while Returning the Object From the Function

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Copy Constructor is not Invoked.

#include 
using namespace std;

```
class Sample
{
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Sample(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a, y = b;
    }
    Sample(Sample &S)
    {
        cout << "Copy Constructor Invoked" << endl;
        x = S.x;
        y = S.y;
    }
};

Sample fun(int a, int b)
{
    Sample temp(a, b);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    Sample S = fun(1, 2);
}
```

I'm Returning the Object from the function 'fun'. it creates the object and return the copy of the object. so it needs to call the copy constructor. But Copy Constructor in Not Invoked.The Output of the Program is Empty

Comment: The compiler is free to optimize away unnecessary copies.  Don't write code that relies on when the copy constructor will be invoked.

Comment: Look for info on copy elision, AKA RVO.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations? You may see [named return value optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)